# How do I make a Python script log out of the shell when it exits?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script in Python for bash.  The script automatically runs when the user logs into the account, and I want it to log the user out when it exits.  I tried using os.system('exit'), but it doesn't work.  How would I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps try `os.system("logout")`. I'm not so sure that'll work either

Comment: I tried that, and I get "sh: logout: not found".

Comment: do `which logout` to figure out where the `logout` command lives. It should return a dirpath. Call `os.system` on that dirpath

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes: It would be nice if you would accept one answer.

Answer (score 5):

Set your python script as the login shell of the user(in /etc/passwd/). This way she will be automatically logged out after the script exits.

Answer (score 4):

You can do some nasty things like just killing the parent:

```
os.kill(os.getppid(), 9)
```

This could be called [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html), but it would be unclean as this would cause your process to die too.

Answer (score 3):

*The script automatically runs when the user logs into the account* - how?  The implication from your question is that it is run from bash.  While I subscribe to @Fredrick Roth's suggestion, an alternative is to run the Python script from the shell using :

```
exec script-name.py
```

The `exec` command replaces the current *program*, so `bash` will be replaced by `python`.  When the Python script ends there will be no shell to return to.

Answer (score 0):

You might kill the tty that you're logged in

OR

this might do the trick

https://github.com/tuwid/kickout

Its a script that logs out a specific user in a tty